# How to fix this query to make it works well with the ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

With a help from my friend, I could be able to come with this complicated query.

```
DECLARE @LastSevenDays DATETIME, @Last30Days DATETIME

SELECT @LastSevenDays = DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)),
       @Last30Days = DATEADD(dd, -30, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

SELECT  [D].DivisionName
,       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DateTimeComplete >= @LastSevenDays THEN UQ.Username ELSE NULL END) AS ParticipantsLast7Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DateTimeComplete >= @LastSevenDays THEN UQ.QuizID ELSE NULL END) AS QuizzesLast7Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Username) AS ParticipantsLast30Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.QuizID) AS QuizzesLast30Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT EM.UserName) AS TotalParticipantsInDivisions
,       COUNT(DISTINCT EM.UserName) - COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Username) [ParticipantsInDivisionsWithoutQuiz]
FROM    employee EM
        INNER JOIN Divisions D
        ON D.SapCode = EM.DivisionCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [UserQuiz] AS UQ
        ON UQ.UserName = EM.UserName
           AND DateTimeComplete >= @Last30Days
GROUP BY [D].[DivisionName]
```

This query will show me the following:

1. total number of participants in the quizzes last week and last month
2. total number of taken quizzes last week and last month
3. total number of employees in each division
4. total number of employees in each division without taking any quiz

the query works fine but now after putting a table in the website and trying to configure it with a SqlDataSource that contains this query to retrieve the information from the database, it asked me to determine the parameter for two variables: @LastSevenDays and @Last30Days and I did not know what I should do with this. Any help please?

I know maybe my question seems easy but I tried a lot and failed with it. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Stick it in a stored proc and call the proc.

Answer (score 0):

@LastSevenDays and @Last30Days are parameters that you're query uses and so the SqlDataSource asks for it.

You can do three things:

- Create a stored procedure and [call it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand.aspx)(see the second example which calls a stored procedure)
- Remove the parameters and insert the DATEADD function everywhere you normally referenced the variable
- Use a [FilterParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterparameters%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your SqlDataSource and set initialize it in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can in-line your variables and have a standard select statement like so:

```
SELECT  [D].DivisionName
,       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) THEN UQ.Username ELSE NULL END) AS ParticipantsLast7Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -7, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) THEN UQ.QuizID ELSE NULL END) AS QuizzesLast7Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Username) AS ParticipantsLast30Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.QuizID) AS QuizzesLast30Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT EM.UserName) AS TotalParticipantsInDivisions
,       COUNT(DISTINCT EM.UserName) - COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Username) [ParticipantsInDivisionsWithoutQuiz]
FROM    employee EM
        INNER JOIN Divisions D
        ON D.SapCode = EM.DivisionCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [UserQuiz] AS UQ
        ON UQ.UserName = EM.UserName
           AND DateTimeComplete >= DATEADD(dd, -30, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
GROUP BY [D].[DivisionName]
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET code, write a method like this:

```
        private DataTable doQuery(DateTime last7Days, DateTime last30Days)
        {
            DataTable result = new DataTable();

            string connectionString = "";//TODO;

            string query = @"
SELECT  [D].DivisionName
,       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DateTimeComplete >= @LastSevenDays THEN UQ.Username ELSE NULL END) AS ParticipantsLast7Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DateTimeComplete >= @LastSevenDays THEN UQ.QuizID ELSE NULL END) AS QuizzesLast7Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Username) AS ParticipantsLast30Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.QuizID) AS QuizzesLast30Days
,       COUNT(DISTINCT EM.UserName) AS TotalParticipantsInDivisions
,       COUNT(DISTINCT EM.UserName) - COUNT(DISTINCT UQ.Username) [ParticipantsInDivisionsWithoutQuiz]
FROM    employee EM
        INNER JOIN Divisions D
        ON D.SapCode = EM.DivisionCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [UserQuiz] AS UQ
        ON UQ.UserName = EM.UserName
           AND DateTimeComplete >= @Last30Days
GROUP BY [D].[DivisionName]
";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastSevenDays", last7Days));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Last30Days", last30Days));


                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sda.Fill(result);
                }

            }

            return result;
        }
```

and then call the method with:

```
DataTable myData = doQuery(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7.0), DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30));
```